# log4j ContentAppender null when static

Tags: java, logging, log4j

When ConsoleAppender is static, I get the following error from log4j:

```
log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [null].
```

Example code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;
public class Logging {
    private static final PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout("[%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss}] [%t] %-6r %-5p %m\n");
    private static final ConsoleAppender consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender(layout);
    private Logger logger;
    private String filterClass;
    private boolean logFlag = false;

    public LoggingExample(Class c) {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(c);
        logger.setAdditivity(false);
        logger.removeAllAppenders();
        logger.addAppender(consoleAppender);
        consoleAppender.activateOptions();
        filterClass = c.getName();
    }

    public log() {
        logger.info("this doesn't work when ConsoleAppender is static!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because `removeAllAppenders()` removes and **closes** all the appenders and the underlying writers. Your console appender's writer is then also closed when you do it <s>because a console appender is already attached to the logger by default</s> if you ever create more than one instance of `LoggingExample`.

Comment: But consoleAppender shouldn't be attached to logger until I specifically attach it with addAppender. I need to remove all the other appenders before that so that the logs are not duplicated. I don't see how consoleAppender is getting closed.

Comment: For some reason I thought `ConsoleAppender`s were special, but it looks like this should work if you're only creating one instance of `LoggingExample`. If you create more than one instance then what I said will definitely happen because your `consoleAppender` is static.

Comment: I am creating more than one instance of LoggingExample. However, I thought this would be ok because the logger is not static.

Comment: In log4j there is always only one logger per name, and since the convention is (like in your case) to give the class name to the logger, it is always going to be the same logger. That is also why people often make the logger `private static final` since using a static logger has the same result as calling `Logger.getLogger` every time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to with the initialization of layout or consoleAppender. How do you know if layout or consoleAppender failed to construct?

I will use **Static Initialization Block** to do whatever logic is necessary to make sure the static objects get created:

```
    public class Logging {
        private static final PatternLayout layout;
        private static final ConsoleAppender consoleAppender;

        static { /* code to initialize layout and consoloAppender  */}
        // Rest of your code
    }
```